# Set as Ringtone android

Tags: android, ringtone

first I want to say that I'm sorry I know there are already questions about this, but I am new to programing and android is my first language.
How can I set my application to set sound from my app as ringtone?
I got this

```
String filepath ="/sdcard/yeahitsworking";
File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);

ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "chinnu");
content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);


//Insert it into the database
Log.i(TAG, "the absolute path of the file is :"+
ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
//Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, content); 
String ringtoneUri = newUri.toString();

Log.i(TAG,"the ringtone uri is :"+ringtoneUri);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getBaseContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);
```

How can I set this so when I click on button Eg. bt1 to set this as ringtone?
Is it something like this

```
ImageButton bt1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

This is not a double post I've searched already and non of them answers my question.

Comment: Means want to set Ringtone click on Button??

Comment: Yeah. I can't figure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your Ringtone on click event of your button.

```
   urbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            String filepath ="/sdcard/yeahitsworking";
            File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringtoneFile .getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile 
                    .getAbsolutePath());
            getContentResolver().delete(
                    uri,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\""
                            + ringtoneFile .getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    YourActivityName.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                    newUri);

        }
    });
```

Comment: um I get this erros: k cannot be resolved, and RingtonesPlaying cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @user3231871 now u can chk

Comment: What should I do with Ringtones playing cannot be resolved to a type?

Comment: chek now..u should paste there your activity name

Answer (score 1):

```
        File k = new File(path, "mysong.mp3"); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        //Insert it into the database
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri newUri = main.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

ImageButton bt1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
          myActivity,
          RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
          newUri
    );
}
});
```

Comment: But how can I set this so when I click on button it sets ringtone?